# how i control 2 picturebox upload photo with one button

Tags: c#, button, picturebox, opendialog

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp";
        fd.ShowDialog();
        pictureBox12.ImageLocation = fd.FileName;
        textBox35.Text = fd.FileName;

        if (pictureBox12.ImageLocation == fd.FileName)
        {
                OpenFileDialog fd2 = new OpenFileDialog();
                fd2.ShowDialog();
                pictureBox11.ImageLocation = fd2.FileName;
        }
    }
```

i have 2 picturebox and 1 upload button i want first time click button and open showdialog and choosephoto and closeshowdialog and again click button this time choose for second picturebox but problem is first time click button and step by step 2 open showdialog

Comment: If you are confused imagine how the user will be.  Why not use 2 buttons?  Or do the dialog twice - once for each PB.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: because i have so many picturebox almoust ten each. i dont wanna for every picturebox use the button this time will be ten button this is ugly for program.